# Android 5.0.1 Nexus 9 not showing connected device in Bluetooth list

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, a2dp

I have a Bluetooth headset device connected to my Nexus 9 running Android 5.0.1.

My app is running the following code, where I call getA2dpConnectedDevice() to check on A2DP status. I expect that since the app device is supposedly connected to the headset that the BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener().onServiceConnected would fire but it does not.

```
private void getA2dpConnectedDevice() {
    // Establish connection to the proxy.
    mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mA2dpProfileListener,
            BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
    logAndPostMessage( "Requesting A2DP connection status");
}

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mA2dpProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.A2DP) {
            mBluetoothA2dp = (BluetoothA2dp) proxy;
            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> a2DPdevices = (ArrayList) mBluetoothA2dp
                    .getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(new int[] { BluetoothA2dp.STATE_CONNECTED });
            // if any connected devices, should only be one
            if (a2DPdevices.size() > 0) {
                addDeviceToDeviceMap(a2DPdevices.get(0), null);
                // post connected msg
                logAndPostMessage(  "A2DP is connected. Fired A2DPStatusUpdate event");
                post(new A2DPStatusUpdate(a2DPdevices.get(0),
                                BluetoothA2dp.STATE_CONNECTED));
                getHeadsetConnectedDevice();

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a problem with my thinking that the above code should work?

Strangely enough (and perhaps a real clue there is a problem in Android), is that although the Bluetooth icon in the status bar indicates the headset is connected, when I go to the Bluetooth setting screen, I do not see the headset at all.

Any words of wisdom would be appreciated.